# Is a dragonfly gem good solution for heavy loaded project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sinatra, dragonfly-gem

Is dragonfly gem good solution for heavy load project ? ( massive social application like Facebook for example)

Because I think it's good solution for small - medium sized projects but I really don't like the idea that the image is rendered on the fly (I know that there is a cashing option but still) I'm concert it might make huge difference if you using it on such a big web application

and also What gem to process images do you think would be best for such large project would best solution and why ? (speed is the main issue)

thx for answers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755662/carrierwave-or-dragonfly/4645846#4645846 I like Luufs post to these topic, but still no answer for my question

Comment: Dragonfly does allow you to do up-front thumbnailing if you want - see http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Models.html#Up-front_thumbnailing - you may want to use a mix of that and on-the-fly, depending on your needs

Answer (score 1):

I don't know dragonfly,  but since you're looking for a scalable solution, you should have a look at [Delayed Paperclip](https://github.com/jstorimer/delayed_paperclip) based on Paperclip and DelayedJob (or Resque).

Picture process will be handled as background job which won't slow down the app and let the user wait in front of his screen.

Comment: I like your idea of images processed in background (+1 for that), I think It would be good solution for images in album, but I think that wouldn't be weary helpfull for avatars or images of products,  because this way there could be a queue of jobs to process  and user wouldn't see the image after reloading page (only after while)

Comment: It would really depend on the queue. I could be quite direct and could be updated thanks to ajax.