# The perfect way to upload file in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm new in Ruby/Rails, so, my question: what is the perfect way to upload file and save filename in database with rails? Are there any Gem? Or maybe there are good build-in feature?

Comment: I'm amazed of how many people ask this same exact question without searching SO first......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 paperclip vs carrierwave vs dragonfly vs attachment\_fu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419731/rails-3-paperclip-vs-carrierwave-vs-dragonfly-vs-attachment-fu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Paperclip.It is most popular gem in rails community...

```
   https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
```

these lines do the all stuff

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
   end
```

Try it......

Answer (score 7):

Also try [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), Ryan has a good screencast about this [gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Answer (score 3):

Just take a look on the links to choose between paperClip & carrierwave :

[Rails 3 paperclip vs carrierwave vs dragonfly vs attachment_fu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419731/rails-3-paperclip-vs-carrierwave-vs-dragonfly-vs-attachment-fu)

And

http://bcjordan.github.com/posts/rails-image-uploading-framework-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

Most people use the [Paperclip Gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).