# Image management and if statement in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image

Consider this

```
if params['image'].nil?
```

1. In html's case, I used the above and it checked the presence of file and
   hence i changed the path accordingly. How can I check it in erb?
2. I have a `<%= f.file_field :IMAGE %>` in my code and when I click on
   the submit button, I have to store my image in a database and use it
   or i want to store the images in files and store the path in database
   so i can display the image later.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can check wether `params['image']` is nil or not, you just have to follow the best practice to store it in an instance that I'm going to call `@image`, although you can be a maverick and use `params['image']` if you want.

```
<% unless @image.nil? %>
  <!-- Code here -->
<% end %>
```

OR

```
<% if @image.nil? %>
  <!-- Code here -->
<% else %>
  <!-- Code here -->
<% end %>
```

2) You can use a gem to support you like [**Dragonfly**](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) or [**Paperclip**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). Check this [Paperclip vs Carrierwave vs Dragonfly's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419731/rails-3-paperclip-vs-carrierwave-vs-dragonfly-vs-attachment-fu) out!

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout some gems like [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), as well as the [Railscast for Paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) and the [Railscast for Carrierwave](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads).