# Which is better Paperclip or CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip, carrierwave

I should choose one of these gems for my project.
Which is better? Is Paperclip more flexible or not?
Thanks!)

Comment: Check this out: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on the situation cannot tell exactly which is better but you may select according to your situation from commonly used three of them:

1. **Paperclip**
2. **Carrierwave**
3. **Dragonfly**

[Differences between three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419731/rails-3-paperclip-vs-carrierwave-vs-dragonfly-vs-attachment-fu)

[And more differences](http://praaveenvr.blogspot.com/2014/03/compare-carrierwave-paperclip-and.html)