# Compare Paperclip and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have tried both of them for different projects. I just use it to upload image with multiple styles to S3.

And I wonder how different they are? Which one is better? In which case we should you paperclip and which case we should use carrierwave?

Comment: This question will lead to primarily opinion based answers.

Comment: I don't think so, I just think these are some cases that we should use paperclip, but another case, it's better to use carrierwave. Same with we should use rails_admin for a simple RESTful admin site, but want more customization, we should use ActiveAdmin

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the situation cannot tell exactly which is better but you may select according to your situation from commonly used three of them:

1. Paperclip
2. Carrierwave
3. Dragonfly

[Differences between three](http://bcjordan.com/posts/rails-image-uploading-framework-comparison/)

[More differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419731/rails-3-paperclip-vs-carrierwave-vs-dragonfly-vs-attachment-fu)

[And more differences](http://praaveenvr.blogspot.fr/2014/03/compare-carrierwave-paperclip-and.html)